# Parsing to an array based on multiple delimiters

Tags: javascript, parsing, pdf

I need to parse the following string (Parsing PDF, would like to avoid third party packages.).

> /Type /Pages /MediaBox [0 0 612 792] /Count 9 /Kids [ 5 0 R 355 0 R ]

I am using Javascript:

```
String.split(' ');
```

The Output I would like to get is [
  '/Type',
  '/Pages',
  '/MediaBox',
  '[0 0 612 792]',
  '/Count',
  '9',
  '/Kids', '[ 5 0 R 355 0 R]'
  ]

This results in: the following output: [ '<<',
  '/Type',
  '/Pages',
  '/MediaBox',
  '[0',
  '0',
  '612',
  '792]',

Specifically, I would like to delimit '[' and ']'. so that the string would read '[ 5, 0, R, 355, 0, R]'

The Final result expected is this:

I am trying to see if I can address this with regular expression and currently I am stuck.

Comment: You are aware that most of the spaces in your example are optional? Those key-value-pairs could also be written as `/Type/Pages/MediaBox[0 0 612 792]/Count 9/Kids[5 0 R 355 0 R]`. Your parsing idea is too simple for that... Furthermore, there can also be comment lines inbetween...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This regex should take care of it

```js
var input = "/Type /Pages /MediaBox [0 0 612 792] /Count 9 /Kids [ 5 0 R 355 0 R ]"
var result = input.match(/(\[[^\]]+\]|\S+)/g)
console.log(result)
```

as an explanation, it groups every character that is not ] between the characters [ and ] ([[^]]+]) OR a sequence of characters that is not a space (\S+)

Comment: Just a pointer, OP needs to replace spaces in `[..]` with comma

Comment: Selected this answer as it is succinct and simple.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regex that will return `[...]` groups and then you can replace `spaces` with `comma`. Then, you just have to split it by `spaces`

```js
var s = "/Type /Pages /MediaBox [0 0 612 792] /Count 9 /Kids [ 5 0 R 355 0 R ]";

var arr_reg = /\[(.*?)(?:\]|$)/g;
s = s.replace(arr_reg, function(str){
  str = str.substring(1,str.length-1);
  return "[" + str.trim().replace(/ /g, ',') + "]"
});
console.log(s.split(' '))
```

Comment: Thanks, Please see my edited question: Can you please explain what the '|$'  at the end of the regex is for?

Comment: @Vinod *Match group that ends with `]`*